# RecyclerView not updated with filteredList

Tags: android, kotlin

I am migrating my code to Kotlin and one of my activities has a ListView with a custom SearchListAdapter.
I have written a new RecyclerViewAdapter that also performs search filtering.

While debugging i found the list to be filtered but the view does not get updated. What am i missing?

I also cannot access the item position in handleItemClick() but only item attributes.

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.ui

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_display_list_item_r.view.*
import com.example.items.Items_r
import com.example.R

class RecyclerAdapter(private val itemList: MutableList<Items_r>, private val clickListener: (Items_r) -> Unit) :
  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {

  private var searchList: List<Items_r>? = null

  class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(item: Items_r, clickListener: (Items_r) -> Unit) {
      itemView.list_item_title.text = item.itemName
      itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(item)}
    }
  }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_list_item_r, parent, false)
    return ItemViewHolder(view)
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ItemViewHolder).bind(itemList[position], clickListener)
  }

  override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size

  override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
      override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
        val charString = charSequence.toString()
        if (charString.isEmpty()) {
          searchList = itemList
        } else {
          val filteredList = ArrayList<Items_r>()
          for (row in itemList) {

            if (row.itemName.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
              filteredList.add(row)
            }
          }

          searchList = filteredList
        }

        val filterResults = FilterResults()
        filterResults.values = searchList
        return filterResults
      }

      override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: FilterResults) {
        searchList = filterResults.values as ArrayList<Items_r>
        notifyDataSetChanged()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

SampleActivity.kt

```
package com.example.ui

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.SearchManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.core.app.NavUtils
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import butterknife.ButterKnife
import com.example.items.Items_r
import com.example.R
import com.example.ui.base.BaseActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_display_list_r.*

class SampleActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private var caller = ""
    private var callerClass: Class<*>? = null

    private var rAdapter: RecyclerAdapter? = null
    private var searchView: SearchView? = null

    /* Access modifiers changed, original: protected */
    override val selfNavDrawerItem: Int
        get() = R.id.title_activity_sample

    override fun providesActivityToolbar(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    /* Access modifiers changed, original: protected */
    public override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(bundle)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list_r)
        ButterKnife.bind(this as Activity)
        setupToolbar()

        val stringArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_sample)
        val searchList = ArrayList<Items_r>()
        for (items in stringArray) {
            searchList.add(Items_r(items))
        }

        rAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(searchList, { i : Items_r -> handleItemClick(i) })
        main_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        main_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        main_recyclerview.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        main_recyclerview.adapter = rAdapter

    }

    private fun handleItemClick(i: Items_r) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LocalActivity::class.java)
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        stringBuilder.append("file:///android_asset/samples/")
        stringBuilder.append(i.itemName)
        stringBuilder.append(".html")
        intent.putExtra("WEBSITE_URL", stringBuilder.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        val actionBarToolbar = getActionBarToolbar()
        actionBarToolbar!!.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_menu)
        actionBarToolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (menuItem.itemId != R.id.title_home) {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
        }
        openDrawer()
        return true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        this.caller = "com.example.ui.MainActivity"
        try {
            this.callerClass = Class.forName(this.caller)
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, Intent(this, this.callerClass))
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView!!.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        //searchView!!.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true)

        searchView!!.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                rAdapter!!.filter.filter(query)
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
                rAdapter!!.filter.filter(query)
                return false
            }

        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

Items_r.kt Model

```
package com.example.items

data class Items_r ( val itemName: String)
```

String Array

```
    <string-array name="list_sample">
        <item>Alpha</item>
        <item>Beta</item>
        <item>Charlie</item>
        <item>Delta</item>
        <item>Alpha Romeo</item>
        <item>Beta Gamma</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `itemList` for binding the data

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ItemViewHolder).bind(itemList[position], clickListener)
  }
```

However, you update `searchList` which does not touch any part of your data in the adapter. You need to update `itemList` in `publishResults`

Comment: Well, i already figured that during debugging. I am new to Kotlin, hence i asked what am i missing. Anyway i have rewritten the adapter with the help of a guide online. I will post the solution. Although I need to test and understand the code since the base functions are written differently.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my adapter code and it works now. I am still not sure why it wasn't working earlier even though i changed to manipulate searchList

```
  private var searchList: List<Items>? = null

  inner class RecyclerViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var itemTitle: TextView? = null

    init {
      itemTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title)
      view.setTag(this);
      view.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onItemClicked(searchList!![adapterPosition], itemList.indexOf(searchList!![adapterPosition]))
      }
    }
  }


  init {
    this.searchList = itemList
  }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    // Inflate XML. Last parameter: don't immediately attach new view to the parent view group
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_item_text, parent, false)

    return RecyclerViewHolder(itemView)
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = searchList!![position]
    holder.itemTitle!!.text = item.itemName
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return searchList!!.size
  }
```

Updated my activity to match the adapter code as well and position of item is also passed using setTag in adapter.

```
{
    val stringArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_sample)
    val itemList = ArrayList<Items>()
    for (items in stringArray) {
        itemList.add(Items(items))
    }
    rAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(itemList, this)

    main_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    main_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
    main_recyclerview.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    main_recyclerview.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    main_recyclerview.adapter = rAdapter
}

override fun onItemClicked(item: Items, position: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, LocalActivity::class.java)
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    stringBuilder.append("file:///android_asset/samples/")
    stringBuilder.append(position)
    stringBuilder.append(".html")
    intent.putExtra("WEBSITE_URL", stringBuilder.toString())
    startActivity(intent)
}
```